# IBKR API historicalData - pandas not loading all rows

Tags: python

I am trying to run an analysis on $TLT Stock using IBKR API to request historical data.

The code being

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading
import numpy as np

class MyWrapper(EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.df=None
        
    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        print("Setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        self.data.append(vars(bar));
        
    def historicalDataUpdate(self, reqId, bar):
        line = vars(bar)
        self.df.loc[pd.to_datetime(line.pop('date'))] = line
        
    def historicalDataEnd(self, reqId: int, start: str, end: str):
        print("HistoricalDataEnd. ReqId:", reqId, "from", {start}, "to", {end})
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)
        self.df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['date'])
        self.df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , errorString)

    def start(self):
        queryTime = ""
        
        contract = Contract()
        contract.secType = "STK" 
        contract.symbol = "TLT"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        

        app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, queryTime, "25 Y", "1 day", "MIDPOINT", 0, 1, True, [])

wrap = MyWrapper()        
app = EClient(wrap)
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 4002, clientId=123)


threading.Thread(target = app.run).start()

import time
time.sleep(5) 

app.disconnect()
```

My terminal shows me

```
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2104  Msg:  Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2107  Msg:  HMDS data farm connection is inactive but should be available upon demand.ushmds
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2157  Msg:  Sec-def data farm connection is broken:secdefil
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2106  Msg:  HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
HistoricalDataEnd. ReqId: 1 from {'19980819  14:28:53'} to {'20230819  14:28:53'}
```

However when I run the code `print(wrap.df.head())`

I get

```
date                                                                     
2016-02-03  128.690  129.935  127.845  127.975      -1        -1     -1.0
2016-02-04  128.660  128.890  127.350  128.725      -1        -1     -1.0
2016-02-05  128.705  128.995  127.585  128.795      -1        -1     -1.0
2016-02-08  128.360  131.625  128.360  131.505      -1        -1     -1.0
2016-02-09  131.210  132.120  130.570  131.275      -1        -1     -1.0
```

Can anyone suggest to me why I am initially being show that the request is from 1998 but the head prints me from 2016?

Thank you.